# C# generate Soap Server from WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, code-generation

We´ve got a WSDL-File which is used for our client-server communication. So we generated a SOAP Service Client from this wsdl file an could successfully transmit data from client to server but now the server we call, need a receive-service where it can put the data generated from the request. So the client calls the server, which asynchronues process the data and after that it will call another soap service to transmit the result. So but the server which calls the consumer soap service has a predefined WSDL which it want to call. To clear that: the Server acts as Client in the situation of transmitting the result from its request.

So far I´ve implemented my own SOAP Service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Wenn der Aufruf dieses Webdiensts aus einem Skript zulässig sein soll, heben Sie mithilfe von ASP.NET AJAX die Kommentarmarkierung für die folgende Zeile auf. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SoapTest : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public System.Single Subtract(System.Single A, System.Single B)
    {
        return (A - B);
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public System.Single Multiply(System.Single A, System.Single B)
    {
        return A * B;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public System.Single Divide(System.Single A, System.Single B)
    {
        if (B == 0) return -1;
        return Convert.ToSingle(A / B);
    }

}
```

Nothing by that, followning this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/write-web-service

But I think its not the right way to write it by my own. So is there a way to generate SOAP Server (the consumer) from a given WSDL? To avoid misunderstandings: I do NOT want to generate a Soap Client!

Comment: If you import the WSDL it will generate the Client. With all the method you need to implement. You can then Extract the interface of that client using Visual Studio(right click extract interface). Then create a new class an inherit from that interface. Use Visual studio to auto implement the interface. You may have to do some cleanup in the interface. and slap some `[ServiceContract]`, and `[OperationContract]` in the interface but that just few coyp past.

Comment: You can off course use reflexion, regex on the generated class to to all of it directly and write all the code. Or use  .NET 5 C# Source Generators for that. But if it's just a one time do it with add web reference method, It will generate the client. then It's just no brain click and few copy past.